# How i can modify ping-reboot script linux

Tags: linux, openwrt

How i can modify ping-reboot script for linux: more than 50% of packages did not receive a response, e.g. to avoid mobile network problems and leave only real not responsed

```
ping -c20 "host"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    reboot
```

Maybe through grep or other?

Comment: something along the lines of `if[ "$(ping -c20 "host" | grep -Po '\d+\% packet loss' | tr -dc 0-9)" -gt 50]; then`

Comment: @hanshenrik With a couple more spaces, though.

Comment: @hanshenrik hi, try this - getting skip the first task and reboot, ping is ok
message: grep unrecognized option:P

Comment: if you're on GNU grep, update to grep version 2.5.1 or newer.. but more likely you're on busybox grep? idk how to do it on busybox grep

Comment: @hanshenrik yep busybox, anyway thx you

Answer (score -1):

php-cli can do it:

> ping -c20 "host" | php -r 'preg_match("/\d+% packet loss/",stream_get_contents(STDIN),$m);if((int)$m[0] === 0){echo "ok";}else{system("restart");}'